# Why is it not showing range value in output?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the range not appearing on the screen in the paragraph with id output?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <label>
        1<input type="range" id="range" min=1 max=12 step=0.1>12
    </label>

    <p id="output"></p>

    <script>
        range.oninput = function() {
        var range= document.querySelector('#range');
        var output= document.querySelector('#output');
            output.innerHtml= range.value;
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: `innerHtml` != `innerHTML`

Comment: As @Mamun has already pointed out, you have a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define variable before working on it as you have used them for functions here
 and,your `output.innerHtml= range.value;` should be `output.innerHTML= range.value;`

**Change your code to**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <label>
        1<input type="range" id="range" min=1 max=12 step=0.1>12
    </label>
    <p id="output"></p>
    <script>
        var range= document.querySelector('#range');
        var output= document.querySelector('#output');
        range.oninput = function() {
            output.innerHTML= range.value;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**Working Example**

```js
var range= document.querySelector('#range');
        var output= document.querySelector('#output');
        range.oninput = function() {
        
         output.innerHTML= range.value;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <label>
        1<input type="range" id="range" min=1 max=12 step=0.1>12
    </label>
    <p id="output"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
output.innerHTML= range.value;
```

not

```
output.innerHtml= range.value;
```

"innerHtml" is not a valid parameter